# Pandas count groupby values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

Example df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b',],
    'value': ['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no']
})
```

I need to count each value in group and get something like this:

```
group yes no
a     3   2
b     1   3
```

I tried `df.groupby(['group', 'value'])['value'].count().to_frame()` and its look fine but too multiindexed, i need simple table like example above

Comment: Use `pd.crosstab(df['group'], df['value'])`

Comment: Fix your code by adding unstack and some formatting: `df.groupby(['group', 'value'])['value'].count().unstack().rename_axis(None,axis=1).reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```py
df.groupby(['group', 'value'])['value'].count().reset_index()
```

next, you can change the column names